# How to improve the performance of rds located in different region

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-server, amazon-rds

I have an AWS Microsoft SQL server in US region.The server is being used by people in Asian region also.But the DML queries take lot of time to execute in the Asian region.
Should I create another SQL server in that region which is in sync with US region?
How can I improve the performance?Please suggest me a cost effective solution.

Comment: i think you already answered your question. i would setup a second SQL and let them sync the diff because this will go faster

Comment: Cost effective would be to move the database closer to the users. If that's not possible you will want a read replica if it's read only use, or if they need to modify the database you could have them run out of an EC2 instance / AWS Workspace in the same region. If you'd described your use cases and scenarios better you'd have gotten better advice - please edit your question if you'd like to provide more information.